# How do I install Tkinter for Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I recently installed Ubuntu as my operating system. I tried installing some python modules; it is giving an error. I am running the command `sudo apt install python3-tk` and the error is:

```
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

If you could help, thank you.

Comment: It looks like you are having problem with one of your sources-list file, which is not related to `tkinter` at all. Just fix the file mentioned in error.

Comment: As the mesage says, the file it references has invalid syntax. So can't say anything without seeing that file.

Comment: If you are still here @ivan_pozdeev; the file says:
deb https://sublimetext.com/apt/stable

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/737498/what-is-the-format-of-the-ubuntu-sources-list-file

Answer (score -1):

There is a slight modification required in the command you used. Can you try,

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-tk
```

instead?

---

Try `sudo apt-get install -qq python-tk`

### It worked in my case.

For Python 2.7, do

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

---

For Python 3+, do

```
sudo apt-get install python3 python3-tk
```

or if you want to remain in Python 2.7, try

```
sudo apt-get install python python-tk
```

Comment: It's giving me the same error. I've tried editing the file given in the error but I can't.

Comment: In my case it isn't working. It's just the same error over and over again

Comment: Which version of Python and Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using python 2.7.17 and Ubuntu 18.04.04 LTS

Comment: Same error. I'll just preinstall my OS if it doesn't work.